# Joomla! 3 installation freezes on installing sample data file

Tags: joomla, installation, sample-data

I am trying to install Joomla 3.3.0 however on step number three installation has been freeze on  installing sample data file and it doesn't finish.

Response is highly appreciate!

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Is this a manual install or application install through your hosting tools?

Comment: It was manual install. Especially I am facing this issue on only local server using XAMPP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Joomla specific installation issue and not programming, you should try the [Joomla Q&A site on StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: OK thanks. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

> This issue is a very common for those who try to install Joomla!
>   locally using XAMPP and WAMP during Joomla! 3 installation process, it
>   hangs forever at the “Creating database tables” step:
>
> Take following steps to solve the problem:
>
> - Go to wamp\www\your-joomla\installation\sql\mysql (if you are using Wampp) or Xampp\htdocs\Your joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql (for
>     Xampp)
> - Open Joomla.sql file find the term ENGINE=InnoDB and replace all with ENGINE=MyIsam

source: http://joomlavi.com/documentation/quickstart-installation-guide